# How to send to server when refresh token?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, retrofit2

How to check this condition and then send to server when refresh token?

1. App deletes Instance ID
2. App is restored on a new device
3. User uninstalls/reinstall the app
4. User clears app data

Here is my code to send server. But is it send all time when app login ? How to send when above condition?

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.e("NEW_TOKEN", s);
    sendRegistrationToServer(s);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<Fcm> call = apiInterface.postFCMToken(user_id, newToken);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Fcm>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Fcm> call, Response<Fcm> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Fcm> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `onNewToken()` is called only once. Current code is fine IMO. That should not send token to server again and again.

Comment: @Shashanth How to send again when refresh token?

Comment: When token refreshed `onNewToken()` will trigger internally. If you want to get current token manually use [this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MainActivity.java#L99) code from Firebase's Github project.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should expect that an app installation is unable to reliably detect when an FCM token changes.  As such, any new token should be unconditionally reported to the backend, as a potential target for messaging for the given user.

The server side of your app can remove invalid tokens by looking at the error response when attempting to send a message to a token that's no longer valid.  If you're using the Admin SDK to [send a message to a device token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_individual_devices), you can detect then when a token is invalid because the API will generate the error **messaging/registration-token-not-registered**, [according to the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/errors).